# How to draw a tree using OpenGL in C#

Tags: c#, opengl

I am still new in OpenGL and I want to draw a tree.

How to do that?

Please help

Thanks

RJ

Comment: http://ins.nafsadh.com/2010/08/02/opengl-tree-as-a-fractal-trigonometric-approach/ here's something to start with

Comment: you mean drawing graphs of a tree structure?

Comment: Fractals, not graphs. They should give you a more realistic look

Comment: thanks on this Ignask.. i'll try this one...

Answer (score 1):

You want a very realistic representation of a tree? Look into using fractals and more specifically Lindenmayer systems or [L-systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). Fractals are self-repeating mathematic constructs that have a lot in common with the way nature and landscape is formed.

I was able to find [this tutorial](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~gz/knowledge/part/doxydoc/index.html), which applies the aforementioned L-Systems to make a tree, using C++.

---

edit: definitely take a look at IgnasK's comment first. That should teach you a lot about using fractals (although admittedly, it will not draw you a nice 3d tree with leafs and all).